# Directive with no decorator - is it ok?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Just going through the docs I noticed that the angular team has an example of cross-field validation where they call the file directive and have no directive decorator.

I am mentioning the file `shared/identity-revealed.directive.ts` here:  https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Since I am using reactive forms only, I would never need to use this validation as a directive. 
Does this make sense? Is it good practice? Why? If not, how would you fix it (i.e. where would you put the file)?

Comment: Nuno, it's only a function (really a const) exported see [export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export). In Angular you can to have .ts that simply expon functions or constant. If you use export, you can use in any another .ts using `import {the-name-your-function-or-const} from './your-file'`. It's usually to have functions, e.g. the function [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) or the functions moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem in cdk-drag module

Comment: Sure I understand that. My question is why would they call it a directive and store it in the directives folder if it doesn't seem like a directive.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am also missing something, but the directive approach is not necessary for reactive forms since we are not focusing on the .html template.

Check this article and its final conclusion:
[Cross field validation](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/add-cross-field-form-validation-with-angular-5b68f1915d62)

> With reactive forms, we don’t need a directive. However, with template-driven forms, we need a directive that runs the validator so that we can add the validator directive to the template and run the validator.